# error id firebase firestore. how to get autoId?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hello i have an issue with firebase (firestore)

```
const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "cities"), {
    name: "Tokyo",
    country: "Japan"
});
console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);

>>Document written with ID:  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

i have try : addDoc setDoc

it always generate my doc with the same ID
any idea ?

Comment: Have you tried add method? There seems add method like db.collection("cities").add({ name: "Tokyo", country: "Japan"}).then((docRef) => {
    console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
})

Comment: i am following https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data?hl=fr#web-version-9_8

Comment: What's the problem with the code you shared?

Comment: i don't get an auto id. all my doc are create with AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA as ID @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: That seems quite unexpected. Can you set up a reproduction on a site like StackBlitz or jsbin, so I can have a look?